# Is there any similar solution to UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I use a `UIWebView` in my app to present content, but now I can't do it anymore because I also need to use a `UIScrollView` and it creates conflicts related to scrolling. 
Also, `UIWebView` is very slow.

So my question is : is there any another way to load string which contains HTML tags (strong, p, div, and etc...)?

**UPDATE (improved explanation)**

I have `UIVIewController` containing an image at the top, and under this image is a title and under the title is content (HTML string from web). The problem is that when the text is too big, the webview is scrolling, but not the whole page. I want the whole page to scroll, not just the webview.

Comment: Not really sure what you're looking for, do you mean another way to properly render HTML?

Comment: @8vius - yes, that I'm looking for.

Comment: @8vius - improved explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
 -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];
    int webViewHeight = [output intValue];
    //NSLog(@"height: %d", webViewHeight);

    if(webViewHeight > 220){

        CGRect frame = articleContentWebView.frame;
        frame.size.height = webViewHeight;
        articleContentWebView.frame = frame;

        int scrollViewheight = 416 + (webViewHeight - 220);
        [articleScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewheight)];

    }

}
```

In delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad I calculate height od UIWebView content and then set height of UIWebVIew and height of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get anything faster or better than the native UIWebView. Probably you should overthink your UI/UX. What exactly do you want to achieve with a webview in a scrollview??

Perhaps attributed strings are enough for you. Look it up.
The OHAttributedLabel even parses HTML for you.

Comment: improved explanation, please take a look at my first post.

Comment: If it's only a single string go for attributed strings and use a UILabel / UITextview instead. If it's more HTML, i would modify the HTML and include your image and title within the HTML and show a fullsized webview.